# Como excluir um ramo(branch) do Git local e remoto?

Tags: git, github

Eu quero apagar um branch local e no meu projeto remoto no GitHub.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Para apagar o branch localmente:

```
git branch -D <nome do branch>
```

Para apagar o branch remotamente:

```
git push <nome do origin> <nome do branch> --delete
```

Comment: Usei o comando para deletar o repositório remoto e deu erro falando que não há nenhum branch. Eu só criei o repositório, mas está vasio. git push <nome do origin> <nome do branch> --delete O nome do origin é o que? No meu caso, coloquei o nome do repositório Teste. E o branch?

Answer (score 15):

Você pode utilizar o seguinte comando:

```
git push origin :nome_do_branch
```

Atentando para os `:` na frente do nome do branch, pois ele quem fará que o branch seja deletado, caso contrário você estaria atualizando o branch remoto.

Comment: Ele quer deletar branch, não subir os commits dele!

Comment: A resposta do Juarez Lustosa por algum motivo vem sendo negativada e ainda tem um comentário dizendo que "ele quer deletar branch, não para subir os commits dele". Porém é uma resposta válida, usada para excluir branchs remotos, e mais simples do que as outras citadas. **antes de `nome_do_branch` tem dois pontos (`:`) e é isso que faz deletar o branch e não fazer o push.**

Comment: Obrigado Rafael Macedo!!! É exatamente isso.

Answer (score 8):

Para remover branch local:

```
 git branch -d nome-do-branch
```

E para remover branch remoto acrescente o flag "-r":

```
 git branch -dr origin/nome-do-branch
```

Comment: git branch -dr origin/nome-do-branch Sobre este comando, onde coloco o nome do meu repositório que chamei de Teste? Criei um repositório, mas não criei branch, não commitei, não fiz nada. Não estou conseguindo apagar o repo Teste. Obs, só tenho remoto, não clonei. Só quero aprender a deletar este projeto.

Comment: Não sei, André. Esse comando aí é apenas para remover branches mesmo, não repositórios.

Comment: @AndréNascimento você pode acessar esse tutorial para aprender a deletar um repositório do GitHub
https://help.github.com/articles/deleting-a-repository/