# Como desativar uma branch no GitHub?

Tags: git, github

Boa tarde,

Tenho um repositório no GitHub com uma branch main, e a idéia é que a cada nova feature, essa seja feita a partir de uma nova branch, que ao final deve ser mesclada com a main, através do merge.

Mas a dúvida é, se é possível, após fazer o merge, desativar essa branch, mas não excluí-la.

Exemplo:

```
git checkout -b novaFeature
```

Feito a alteração e então

```
git commit -m "Nova Feature"
git push origin novaFeature
git checkout main
git merge novaFeature
```

Até então tudo certo, só que se a cada nova feature, se for feito isso, vai gerar um monte de branchs que ao meu ver podem acabar poluindo e bagunçando o repositório.

Queria saber se há alguma forma de após realizar o merge a branch ficar inativa, mas não apagá-la.

Minha primeira vez postando aqui, espero ter conseguido fazer a pergunta corretamente.

Abraço a todxs!

Comment: Se não quer apagar o branch, é só não mexer mais nele. Mas se não quer que eles fiquem no repositório, apague :-)

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Como excluir um ramo(branch) do Git local e remoto?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/61428/como-excluir-um-ramobranch-do-git-local-e-remoto)

Comment: @hkotsubo, faz sentido.

Comment: @PedroSanção eu dei uma olhada nesse link, mas não queria excluir, acredito que seria algo mais próximo da resposta do Ruan Montelo, talvez impedir que uma branch pare de receber pushes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por experiência (e como mencionado no comentário do @hkotsubo), se não quiser uma branch local e/ou remota, basta apagar a branch, pois não há como *desabilitar*, [apenas impedir que *pushes* sejam feitos para o repositório remoto da branch em questão](https://docs.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/about-protected-branches). O ponto de ter um sistema de versionamento, tratando do *Git* nesse post, é justamente **ter um histórico das alterações de todas as versões compartilhadas para que isso não seja necessário**.

Caso queira um histórico mais "limpo" das suas versões, especialmente as mais importantes (como a branch `main` no exemplo do GitHub) é possível aprovar um [Pull Request](https://docs.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/about-pull-requests) (ou fazer um merge) usando [rebase](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase).

A própria ferramenta do GitHub dá a opção para isso e a exclusão da branch em sequência durante a aprovação de um Pull Request, recomendo pesquisar sobre para manter um histórico conciso da versão principal do projeto.

Espero ter ajudado de alguma forma.

Comment: "apenas impedir que pushes sejam feitos para o repositório remoto da branch em questão"
Você tem algum material onde possa olhar essa situação, acredito ser isso que busco.

Comment: Editei a resposta para incluir a referência solicitada.

Comment: Obrigado @ruan-montelo, seria isso mesmo, meu projeto é privado, e sendo assim essa funcionalidade está apenas para contas GitHub Pro.
Vlw!

Answer (score 0):

O comando para apagar uma branch remota é o `push`. Como o parâmetro da branch pode usar o `:` para usar nomes diferentes para a branch local e remota, com ele também é possível apagar.

`git push origin :novaFeature`

Como não tem nada antes dos `:` ele é interpretado como "envie nada para a branch novaFeature", apagando no servidor remoto.

Comment: Entendi, mas nesse caso não queria apagar a branch, seria deixar ela inativa, conforme esse [link](https://docs.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/about-protected-branches), mas obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: realmente, entendi errado a pergunta, mas tudo bem que vale para outras pessoas que caírem aqui